# Reading a String array from a BufferedReader

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I am implementing a client server application. from the server i am sending a String array, and now i want to read whats in that string array from my client code. How can i do this;

When i print the value from the client i get the output something like `[Ljava.lang.String;@120d10`

server:

```
try {
                    PrintWriter r= (PrintWriter) i.next();

                    String[] s={"f","ff"};
                    r.println(s);

                    r.flush();
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
```

client:

```
try {
                    while ((somestring= r.readLine()) != null) {
                        //When i print it i get something like [Ljava.lang.String;@120d10


                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to println the array of strings, instead of each string in the array.  Try something like this on the server:

```
    try {
                PrintWriter r= (PrintWriter) i.next();

                String[] s={"f","ff"};
                for(String sElement : s)
                {
                    r.println(sElement);
                    r.flush();
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
```

Answer (score 3):

When you print an array, it call toString() on it first.  The default toString() for an array prints the `type @ hashCode` which is generally useless.

What you intended was something like

```
String[] arr={"f","ff"};
for(String s: arr)
    r.println(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

`r.println(object)` calls `object.toString()` to know what to print. The arrays `stringTo()` method return just that value (`[L` means you are dealing with an array).

If you want to print all the array, loop it.

```
for(String  str : s) {
  r.println(str + delimiter);
}
```

Of course, you will have to find a valid delimiter (one that does not appear inside your strings).

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) / [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) instead. Then you can send all kinds of Serializable objects (including arrays) directly.